# Oracle Advanced Queue - Removing Message after Dequeue

Tags: java, oracle, jms, advanced-queuing

We're using Oracle JMS APIs to read messages from Advanced Queue. We use the following piece of code to read the messages from the queue:

```
    MessageConsumer consumer = sess.createConsumer(q);


    for (Message m; (m = consumer.receive()) != null;) 
    {
          new Timer().schedule(new QueueExample(m), 0);
    }
```

The problem is, after the message is received from the queue, it is not completely removed from the queue table, only the STATE field is changed from 0 to 2. Is this the default behavior of the Oracle JMS Client? We would like to completely remove the record from the queue table, after the message has been read from the queue with consumer.receive() method. What is the appropriate api method to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **you are experiencing this due to the `retention_time` parameter on your queue being configured** to some high value.

Retention is used for:

> Users can specify that messages be retained after consumption. The
>   systems administrator can specify the duration for which messages will
>   be retained. Oracle AQ stores information about the history of each
>   message, preserving the queue and message properties of delay,
>   expiration, and retention for messages destined for local or remote
>   recipients. The information contains the ENQUEUE/DEQUEUE time and the
>   identification of the transaction that executed each request. This
>   allows users to keep a history of relevant messages. The history can
>   be used for tracking, data warehouse and data mining operations.

You can verify this by checking the queue-creation script and alter the setting via admin interface or using `ALTER_QUEUE`.

Comment: You are right. retention_time was set to INFINITE. Therefore, the message was not removed from the queue after consumption. I changed the retention_time to 0 and now the message is successfully removed from the queue. Thanks for your help!